# Thread Safe Integer Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mutex, atomic

I have a situation where I have a legacy multi-threaded application I'm trying to move to a linux platform and convert into C++.

I have a fixed size array of integers:

int R[5000];

And I perform a lot of operations like:

R[5] = (R[10] + R[20]) / 50;

R[5]++;

I have one Foreground task that mostly reads the values....but on occasion can update one.  And then I have a background worker that is updating the values constantly.

I need to make this structure thread safe.

I would rather only update the value if the value has actually changed.  The worker is constantly collecting data and doing calculation and storing the data whether it changes or not.

So should I create a custom class MyInt which has the structure and then include an array of mutexes to lock for updating/reading each value and then overload the [], =, ++, +=, -=, etc?  Or should I try to implement anatomic integer array?

Any suggestions as to what that would look like?  I'd like to try and keep the above notation for doing the updates...but I get that it might not be possible.

Thanks,
WB

Comment: It's unclear what "atomic" means in the case of `R[5] = (R[10] + R[20]) / 50` - do you mean you need to read `R[10]` and `R[20]` in such a way that one of them can't change before you read the other?  Do you mean that a reader can't read `R[5]` while that calculation is happening?  You can see the difficulties there with scoping the "atomicity".  By comparison, `R[5]++` is the usual sort of thing that atomicity applies to.

Comment: So R[5] is going to get updated.  What I want to ensure is A - Nobody reads R[5] mid update from another thread.  B - The calculation using R[10] and R[20] don't pull the values while another thread is midway through the update.  If R[10] or R[20] has a value change AFTER I've pull my value...I don't care...I get that update next pass.

Comment: So it is okay that R[10] is read then either R[10] or R[20] is updated then R[20] is read?  In other words, you will be computing R[5] by adding two inconsistent values?  Well, that's important to know as it relates to your need for 'atomicity'.  I suggest you follow the plan outlined by @JeremyFRiesner below - start with global locking to ensure reliable repeatable correct running of your legacy program (I know well how difficult it is to do anything with legacy programs, believe me) and then test to see if you need to do better and then refine while testing each change.

Comment: You have it exactly.  The data is coming in from the real world via a PLC and the Control is calculating...but occasionally the user will input a new factoring value which is used to re-scale the real world data.  If they do that mid scan...I'm off for a 1/10 of a second....then the next scan it comes back in line.  I will put in a global mutex and run a test and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Good luck with your legacy app!  Given that you have a periodic 'scan' to do the reading - I might suggest another approach that, sadly, will not be as easy to do into a legacy app.  New values should go into another "update" array as they arrive, as pairs: index + new value.  This is only written to by your updating process - very little contention between reader/writer.  At the start of the scan you "flip" to a second clean "update array" (ping pong fashion) and the first thing the scan does is process all pending updates at once, then does its scan.  Very little contention in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is make the program work reliably, and the easiest way to do that is to have a Mutex that is used to control access to the entire array.  That is, whenever either thread needs to read or write to anything in the array, it should do:

```
the_mutex.lock();
// do all the array-reads, calculations, and array-writes it needs to do
the_mutex.unlock();
```

... then test your program and see if it still runs fast enough for your needs.  If so, you're done; that's all you need to do.

If you find that the program isn't fast enough due to contention on the mutex, you can start trying optimizations to make things faster.  For example, if you know that your threads' operations will only need to work on local segments of the array at one time, you could create multiple mutexes, and assign different subsets of the array to each mutex (e.g. mutex #1 is used to serialize access to the first 100 array items, mutex #2 for the second 100 array items, etc).  That will greatly decrease the chances of one thread having to wait for the other thread to release a mutex before it can continue.

If things still aren't fast enough for you, you could then look in to having two different arrays, one for each thread, and occasionally copying from one array to the other.  That way each thread could safely access its own private array without any serialization needed.  The copying operation would need to be handled carefully, probably using some sort of inter-thread message-passing protocol.

Comment: I know one mutex for the entire array isnt going to be sufficient.  What I want to do is not allow anyone to read a value mid update of that value.  My control plant function executes 10x/second.  And it does 99.5% ofthe updates to the array.  the Viewer Thread is event based and merely reads the values from the array 99.5% of the time.  Occasionaly the Viewer Thread might update one of the values and I don't want the control plant function to access it mid-write/update.

Comment: Don't make predictions about whether it will be sufficient or not -- try it and see for yourself.  The actual behavior of CPUs regarding what turns out to be costly and what doesn't is often counterintuitive, and since a single-mutex solution is trivial (e.g. 5-10 minutes) to implement, you could save yourself a lot of unnecessary work and debugging by doing the simplest thing first.  If, as you suspect, it's not sufficient, then is the time to start working on something more elaborate.